# how can i implement association between two classes in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class student { *attributes* } ;
class course {  } ;
class semester { } ;
```

Relation among these three classes like this 
             [image: UML Diagram of student , course , semester]

Student take course in a semester. Course is not particular to the semester. It can be chosen in any semester by a student. So, This is a ternary relationship among these objects.

There exists a ternary association between these three classes. How do I implement the association between these three classes ? or, In general What are the possible ways to implement association between classes (in c++ or java) ?

Comment: It really depends on the details of how these classes are supposed to interact. But in general, keep the coupling low.

Comment: Voting to close as *not constructive*, because without further specification of the requirements, the question is just too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to say without more details, but from real life examples one could imagine that some courses are given during a semester, and that some students take some courses. The `student` class doesn't need to know anything about `course`s, and the `course` class doesn't need to know anything about `students`. Neither needs to know about `semester`s either. A natural composition would be to give a `semester` a map of `course` to a list of `student`s:

```
class semester 
{
 public:
  // accessors: list of courses, list of students, list of students for 
  // a given course... all obtainable from map.
 private:
  std::map<course, std::set<student>> enrollment;
};
```

Here I use an `std::set` for the students, since students are unique in each course. Likewise for the `std::map`: courses are unique in a semester. Of course, these constraints can be applied manually on top of other non-unique data structures.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to implement associations. In your case you can get away with:

```
class student {
};

class course {
   std::vector<student> students;
};

class semester {
   std::vector<course> courses;
};
```

In more complex cases you may need a complex data structure, a tree or a hash table to represent the relations.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be container-ship, i.e. having an object of another class as a member of one class. e.g. (assuming a student takes 5 courses)

```
class student{
  //other members
  course courseList[5];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion in this case is to make the semester part of the description of a course. Then look at combining students against semester specific courses using a `multimap`.

It nearly sounds like a good problem for a relational database, depending on the app, you might want to farm out the data relationships to the database.